# Excel: sort data from several areas together

Tags: excel, sorting

given two named areas in Excel,
AREA49 (header row and data, Date Format YYYY-MM-DD):

| Date | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-27 | ABC | 111 |

and AREA50:

| Date | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-10 | DEF | 500 |
| 2022-08-30 | XYZ | 999 |

Result should be all together in AREA51, sorted by date (on an extra sheet):

| Date | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-10 | DEF | 500 |
| 2022-05-27 | ABC | 111 |
| 2022-08-30 | XYZ | 999 |

AREA51 should be updated whenever data in AREA49 or AREA50 is modified by adding/removing/updating rows.

Is it possible to achieve this in excel without(!) VBA code?

thank you

Comment: Does your Excel version support dynamic array formulas?

Comment: Excel Version 2016, so I guess no support for dynamic array formulas

Comment: So both Named Ranges include the header row?

Comment: yes. But I can change this if it is needed to solve the problem